# video play loop play another ja

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I need a video to play and loop seamlessly a defined number of times, then skip to a next video and loop seamlessly a defined number of times, and so forth until the playlist ends.

In one page, a user defines videos to be played, as well as how many times it will "loop" (or iterate). These are stored using session variables as:

`$_SESSION["Exer[" .$x. "]"]`

`$_SESSION["Reps[" . $x. "]"]`.

*I'm ignoring this aspect (the php stuff) currently*

I have code that independently works, one that loops and one that plays playlists, but I can't seem to manage the merger of them together to achieve functionality. The code is as followed:

HTML

```
<video width="320" height="240" id="myVideo" autoplay="autoplay">
</video>
```

JavaScript
For looping:

```
<script>
var iterations = 1;

document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;
document.getElementById('myVideo').src = "Video/01.mp4";
myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {    

    if (iterations < 3) {       

        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        iterations ++;

        document.getElementById('iteration').innerText = iterations;

    }   

}, true);
</script>
```

For playlist:

```
<script>
var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0] = "Video/01.mp4";
videoSource[1] = "Video/02.mp4";
videoSource[2] = "Video/03.mp4";
videoSource[3] = "Video/04.mp4";
var i = 0; // define i
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource [videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); // play the video


function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == (videoCount - 1)) {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(i);
    } else {
        videoPlay(i);
    }
}
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried after merging it? if not then try it and post that code if you encounter with problem

Comment: I've attempted merging the two multiple (many and many) times... I can

Comment: then show that code

Comment: It always results in no video or, if I have the looping component first, it pauses after the looping and doesn't progress to the next video.

Comment: 1 example of attempted code (does not work... loops through 1st video, then pauses):

Comment: I told you to post that code

Comment: not really sure how to update trialed code... code is too long for comment box. Amogh, not sure best way to show code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net, show only necessary part

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ngyp1vtz/   Hope the link works!

Comment: If you have codded that, then you code very pathetic!! I have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this, this java script code will replay a video for mentioned number of times and then plays next video if exists in playlist:

```
var eachVdoLoop = 2;
var currentVdoLoop=0;
var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0] = "http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4";
videoSource[1] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
var videoCount = videoSource.length;
var vdoIndex=0;
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);

nextVideo();


function myHandler() {
    currentVdoLoop++;
    if(currentVdoLoop < eachVdoLoop)
    {
            document.getElementById("myVideo").play();      
    }
    else
    {
            vdoIndex++;
            currentVdoLoop=0;
            nextVideo();
    }
}

function nextVideo() {
    if(vdoIndex == videoSource.length)
    {
      alert("Playlist ended!!!")
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[vdoIndex]);    
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
```

An working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngyp1vtz/2/) (fiddle updated)